# DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST

Tags: laravel, controller, resources, destroy

I'm using laravel 9.x
my route is

```
Route::middleware('verified')->group(function (){
    
    Route::get('dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
    
    Route::resource('kullanicilar', UserController::class);    
});
```

and my controller has destroy methods

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        
        echo 'destroy'.$id;
        //User::find($id)->delete();
        //return redirect()->route('kullanicilar.index')
        //    ->with('success','Kullanıcı başarı ile silindi.');
        
    }
```

and my user_index.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" aciton="{{ route('kullanicilar.destroy',$user->id) }}" style="display:inline">
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
</form>
```

even though everything seems to comply with the rules, I'm getting this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the action element causing the form to be posted back to the same route as the original page;

```
<form method="POST" aciton="{{ route('kullanicilar.destroy',$user->id) }}"
```

note `action` is misspelled

Also, as you are using resource controller, you should accept the model in the destroy method.

Use Route::list to check what your controller should accept

Comment: if I get my routelist from artisan command, I see include delete method
DELETE          kullanicilar/{kullanicilar} ............. kullanicilar.destroy › UserController@destroy

Comment: and I see google browser my aciton true for laravel documentation , ture.
<form method="POST" aciton="http://127.0.0.1:8000/kullanicilar/8" style="display:inline">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="yN5A3IO9l9TUCxvVaWyK7xfptUdJXh3kx2oJaqO0">                                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">         

you can check documentation                           
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller

Comment: oppps! I see now. acition -> action . ok thanks.

Answer (score 1):

action **NOT** aciton in Your Form Ex :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('kullanicilar.destroy',$user->id) }}" 
  style="display:inline">
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: oppps! I was embarrassed. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by overriding the destroy method with get on the web.php route. it's working for me for now.

such as

```
 //this should be at the top
Route::get('kullanicilar/remove/{id}', [UserController::class,'destroy'])->name('kullanicilar.remove'); 
Route::resource('kullanicilar', UserController::class);
```

and change my user_index.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('kullanicilar.remove',$user->id) }}"  title="Sil" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

it works.

Comment: it works this way because you expect to receive ID in your controller.  Your code is confused because the resource route is called kullanicilar but you pass User model to it.  If you do not have model kullanicilar, do not use a resource route, but instead list the endpoints individually